# Trying to pass param from front end to backend without refreshing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I could not solve a problem based on webforms in dotNet Framework.
Tring to get images in modal by click on picture and displaying images which contain specific stored procedure.

I have Web User Control which contains two section of following code, which main part is:

```
    <div class="row">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Galleries" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="column">
                <img src="<%=DomainName %>/<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>" onclick="openModal();iButtonClick(<%# Eval("IdMaster") %>)" style="width:100%; height:180px;" class="hover-shadow cursor"> 
                <h2><%# Eval("Title") %></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

...and there is modal

```
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-content">

        <asp:Repeater ID="slider_repeater_active_modal" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="mySlides">
                    <img src="<%=DomainName %>/<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>" style="width:100%">
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

By click of image I do get idMaster successfully as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function iButtonClick(idMasterGallery) {
    console.log(idMasterGallery);
    // TODO HERE
}
```

But taken id should proceed through a method and get specific images in modal.
The backend:

```
        DataSet ds = new Base().CP_GalleryDetail_GetWithPager(1, 8);
        Galleries.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        Galleries.DataBind();

        DataSet dsGetSliderModal = new Base().CP_GalleryDetail_Get(x);
        slider_repeater_active_modal.DataSource = dsGetSliderModal;
        slider_repeater_active_modal.DataBind();
```

The idMaster from userclick should enter in the place of "x" to get specific images, but this has to be without refreshing the page.

Tried with with ajax to Get or Post as WebMethod in c#, also tried asp:Images but unsuccessful because it is ascx file, tried as different as asp click action but I could not use asp action in img tag...

Overall, trying to archive: I have multiple galleries and inside of those multiple galleries I have multiple images, when user clicks in in gallery Modal opens with the images of those galleries, in the backend part of the problem it works fine I do get successful result, but not in frontend part.

Comment: ASP. NET webforms are fundamentally based on the postback. if you want to do something that functions like a single page app and refreshes without the whole page refreshing you should consider using MVC and jQuery to get the result you're looking for

Comment: Yes, but complete application is created with webforms and at this point I cannot change the structure of application.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't databind to a repeater without a postback, unfortunately...Some possible approaches might be to prepopulate a modal for each gallery on the page at load, and then use javascript to open the correct one when the image is clicked, or (probably better, but requires more javascript coding) use ajax and a web method to retrieve the list of images (maybe as json) and use javascript to populate them into the modal.

Comment: I tried using ajax and web method but it wasn't working for me or I couldn't get working...

Comment: To be clear, you cannot use ajax/web method to databind a repeater, if that's what you were trying. You would need to use javascript to get the data into the modal. If the issue was something else, add some code samples to show exactly what you tried, or maybe open a new question on that subject. You also would probably be able to find some sample code via google easily enough for how to retrieve data with ajax and how to use javascript to add html to a page.